# mondrian.xml schema files pentaho location

Tags: pentaho, olap-cube, mondrian

I'm creating cubes (xml schemas) via schema-workbench or ivy schema editor.
When I'm publishing it, I would like to know where the schemas (mondrian.xml files) are actually saved,What is the location of these files?

Thanks,

Answer (score 5):

Which version of Pentaho BA server are you using? Pre or Post 5.0?

Pre 5.0: you choose the file path when publishing. The path is under you ${BISERVER}/pentaho-solutions.

5.0 and beyond: there's no physical file, it's stored in Pentaho's Jackrabbit repository only.

Comment: Is there a way to extract xml file from bytea postgres field?

Comment: You can download it directly from the Penthao user console: go to Manage Data sources, choose your Analysis source and click on the download button.

Comment: tnx, I know it, but it says that specific file is corrupted so I can't download it but schema/cube is working normaly.

Answer (score 0):

If you create any Analysis in Mondrian 5.*, and you have a test server and prod server, don't export Mondrian schemas from one to another. For a mystical reason you won't be able to get rid of them later.

This was my case, when I started searching for the pentaho-solutions/system/olap/datasources.xml in order to delete the problematic mondrian scheme. This source just doesn't exist anymore.

All data is now saved with the help of Jackrabbit. Jackrabbit stores your Mondrian Schemas together with all other Reports and Analysis to the database (the path is given in the jackrabbit preference file). But in the database you can only see their IDs. So there is no chance to get rid of one object - you leave everything or delete everything by truncating the table. The main problem is, that in the same table are saved not only schemas, but also all other reports, which you have downloaded to the server.